# change image jQuery without making a new request to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, httprequest

I am using jQuery to change a background image every second. This is working as I want, however, when I look at the `NETWORK` tab in Google chrome I see that a new GET request is made for the image every second which is obviously very uneconomical. Can anyone advise a better approach to take here. I have read on other posts that the images should be cached and that the browser should know not to make a request to the server, but as far as I can tell the browser is still making the request.

Please see current code below.

```
var x = 0,
homepageImages = ["1","2","3","4"];

setInterval(function(){ 
   x++;
   if(x === 4){
     x = 0;
   }  
  $('.desktop-main-img').attr('src', 'img' + homepageImages[x]  + '.jpg');
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: @Pete yeah, i think that seems like the road i need to take!

Answer (score 1):

You want to preload the images then.

```
var x = 0,
homepageImages = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

// invisible preload the images
for( var i = 0; i < homepageImages.length; i++ )
    $(new Image()).src('img' + homepageImages[i]  + '.jpg');

setInterval(function()  {
    x = ++x === 4 ? 0 : x;
    $('.desktop-main-img').attr('src', 'img' + homepageImages[x]  + '.jpg');
}, 1000);
```

But keep in mind, the network tab may show a get request for the images. But you should see, that the response is cached. The server tell your browser, that the image has not changes/he already knowns the image and will transfer no data.

Comment: and will this not happen the way my code is already working? Why does adding the first loop change anything?

Comment: Sure, your code does. I was thinking you want to preload the image, because of the flickering when the images is loaded within the change. With the loop above, you have no further loading within your interval and your images are already chached then ...

Answer (score 0):

you must preload all images in body before run that loop